# How to decrypt a PDF which contains an encryption dictionary flags specifying the allowed operations - Python PYPDF2

Tags: python, java, pdfbox, pypdf

I am reading PDF through Python PYPDF. The PDF file which contains an encryption dictionary flags specifying the allowed operations (Signing: Not Allowed).

[image]

I want to decrypt the PDF file. I used following but not working for me.

```
pdf = PdfFileReader(pdf_file, strict=False)
pdf.decrypt(b'')
pdf.getPage(0)
```

I got the following error when passing this pdf to JAVA library Apache PDFBox jar.

> ERROR: PDF contains an encryption dictionary, please remove it with setAllSecurityToBeRemoved()

How to fix this in my python code before send pdf to Java library?

Comment: is your question about pypdf or about pdfbox? What calls to PDFBox are you using, what parameters are you passing?

Comment: I am using PDFBox  jar with my Python application. Hence I don't want to change anything on jar library since the error comes from JAR. I need to decrypt before pass the pdf to JAR.

Comment: Did you add it or was already like that? Have you tried to inspect the pdf.getDocumentInfo()? –